# Kdevelop 4 link glew and freeglut

Tags: opengl, kdevelop, kdevelop4

How can I link glew and freeglut to my project using Kdevelop 4? The functions of glut and opengl shows in code completion suggestion list but it fails with undefined reference to glut functions when I build it. How and what things do I have to set up? paths? flags?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the linker flags `-lGLEW -lglut`